# For Multi-Broker kafka setup, What should be the value of listeners and advertised.listeners?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I have a confluent OSS setup in AWS with three brokers, three zookeepers and two workers. At the time of configuring server.properties in one of the workers, I got stuck with the config of `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` properties.

I searched for the solution and everywhere it is advised to set properties of `listeners` and `advertised.listeners`.
I tried with the following properties :

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<public-ip-of-worker>:9092
```

also tried :

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

With the above settings the issues :

Kafka Connect server gives the following error :

```
    [2019-07-17 13:03:19,067] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=connect-cluster] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9781 : {connect-statuses=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:968)
    [2019-07-17 13:03:19,170] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=connect-cluster] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9782 : {connect-statuses=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:968)
```

And whenever we try to create/delete a topic using KSQL we get the error :

```
[2019-07-17 12:53:08,351] WARN Timeout to get commandStatus, waited 5000 milliseconds:, statementText:TERMINATE CSAS_YP_SINK_TOPIC_38; (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.resources.KsqlResource:375)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.CommandStatusFuture.get(CommandStatusFuture.java:76)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.CommandStatusFuture.get(CommandStatusFuture.java:29)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.resources.KsqlResource.distributeStatement(KsqlResource.java:373)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.resources.KsqlResource.executeStatement(KsqlResource.java:334)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.resources.KsqlResource.handleKsqlStatements(KsqlResource.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**So now, I am confused with the `server.properties` configuration for our cluster, whether to use workers IP into listeners or brokers IP.
If it is brokers IP, we have three brokers and we are unable to set all brokers with the same port?**

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Sharing my Connect and KSQL properties:

**Connect** https://www.writeurl.com/publish/15z9zu3j5k5jxim1k81d

**KSQL** https://www.writeurl.com/publish/uvtlxgbld369hpahozju

Comment: How about `listeners=PLAINTEXT://<public-ip>:9092` ?

Comment: Maybe share your Connect and KSQL properties. You could also test connections with console producer and consumer

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous <public-ip> of two workers or <public-ip> of the three brokers ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Shared my Connect and KSQL properties. Console producer and consumer are running fine.

Comment: What do you mean "workers"? If you are trying to get just Kafka working, you only have brokers. If you are comfortable with Ansible, you could use that https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/cp-ansible/docs/index.html or there is also an AWS quickstart CloudFormation script to set these up for you